# Problema con la respuesta de ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony2

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Symfony y al momento de mandar los datos por ajax la respuesta que genero con un `json_encode()` me da error

Este es mi código del ajax

```
$.ajax ({
    data: {"id": id_category, "type": "add_row_interno"},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{{ path('acme_smart_action') }}",
    success: function (rescue_data,status) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(rescue_data));
    },
    error:function (rescue_data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(rescue_data));
    }
});
```

función respuesta

```
public function showRowProducts($id_service)
{
    $result["result"] = "result";
    return new Response(json_encode($result));
}
```

y obtengo lo siguiente en error

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"result\":\"result\"}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: Eso no se ve como un error precisamente, podrías especificar __que es lo que esperas obtener__ que te hace pensar que la actual respuesta es un error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto ya viene formateado en JSON

Cambia esto:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(rescue_data));
```

Por esto:

```
console.log(rescue_data);
```

Obs: Revisalo en el panel "console" de tu browser y no uses alerts para estas cosas.